# Scoping in React + React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, flux

I am having a scoping issue. I can console.log this.props.routeParams.key from within the constructor. But when outside of the constructor, within the filterList function, I get the error  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined". What's my scoping issue? Why can it read the this from within the constructor but not from within the filterList function?

I am using React Router + Flux + React.

```
import AltContainer from 'alt-container';
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import Blogger from './Blogger'
import List from './List'
const rootURL = 'https://incandescent-fire-6143.firebaseio.com/';

import BlogStore from '../stores/BlogStore'
import BlogActions from '../actions/BlogActions';


export default class BlogShow extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    {console.log(this.props.routeParams.key)}
}


filterList(key) {
  if (this.props.routeParams.key===key){
    return Blogstore.state.blog
  }
}

  render() {
             {Object.keys(BlogStore.state.blog).map(this.filterList)}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

that is happening because your filterList function is not bound to your component

Bind it in your constructor

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.filterList = this.filterList.bind(this);
}
```

You read about it [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#no-autobinding)

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly correct. Can you please explain the logic behind this?

Comment: as I said, if you don't bind the function to your component, "this" is going to be undefined because there is no autobinding in ES6 classes. If the answer helped you, you should accept it.

Comment: Yeah, you should do that when an answer solves your problem :P http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Thank you for your help!